# MacBook Pro 16 2019 i7 - CPU throttling

Tags: performance, cpu, temperature

My MacBook Pro starts to throttle its CPU to 0.8 - 1GHz over time, even when watching 2k youtube videos, which of course is not a normal behaviour.

Here are some details about my issue. First, **pmset**:

[image]

**Macs Fan Control**:

[image]

[image]

**Intel Power Gadget**:

[image]
[image]

As you can see temperatures are not high, but CPU throttles very extensively.

1. My MacBook is charged by original 96W charger
2. There are no external peripherals connected
3. Room temperature is normal (20-23 celsius)
4. The same thing is happening to basically any other more demanding CPU applications, like FL Studio
5. Battery is ok

What can cause this issue? I already tried to reset SMC, turned off wifi, bluetooth, etc.  - nothing helped.

Comment: Make sure that Mac Fan Control isn't setting fan limits that might cause overheating.  Otherwise, it could be dust/fluff built-up inside.

Comment: Side question: are you actually getting 60+ degrees on CPU while running just on 5 watts and having fans on full blast? I mean, no way it's possible to reach even 45 degrees with just 5 watts of consumption and fans fully engaged, and you're at over 60.

Comment: "Core REQ", which is requested-by-system frequency is also extremely low, which hints that it's definitely system and not a third party app that's limiting the power. What was the battery level at that moment? Is battery actually ok? Apple is known to severely throttle the power if there's something wrong with battery.